# Erlang error logging in plaintext

Tags: logging, erlang

I currently have an OTP application for which I'm using SASL error logging. The logs go to binary encoded files which I have to use the rb library to read. This is a major pain, since what I really would like is to be able to export all the logs to plaintext and bash my way through them. I've found one comment on an old mailing list that gave some links to alternate error_loggers:

http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Lots-of-questions-about-error-logger-td2109935.html

But the code is outdated and throws tons of errors when I try to compile it. Are there any newer libraries I can use to send SASL messages to a plaintext files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sasl event framework to create your own event handler.
The detail explanation is in book "Manning.Erlang and Otp in action, part 2 chapter 7, page 170(maybe diferent for different version) "logging and event handling the erlang/otp way

For actual code, please read couchdb's http://couchdb.apache.org/downloads.html source code file "couch_log.erl" and "couch_event_sup.erl", the first file is event handler, the second file is gen_server wrapping module for "couch_log".

The following codes is quoted from the "couch_log.erl" file for explanation

```
-behaviour(gen_event). %<======event handler OTP module behaviour
init([]) ->
    % read config and register for configuration changes

    % just stop if one of the config settings change. couch_server_sup
    % will restart us and then we will pick up the new settings.
    ok = couch_config:register(
        fun("log", "file") ->
            ?MODULE:stop();
        ("log", "level") ->
            ?MODULE:stop();
        ("log", "include_sasl") ->
            ?MODULE:stop()
        end),

    Filename = couch_config:get("log", "file", "couchdb.log"),
    Level = level_integer(list_to_atom(couch_config:get("log", "level", "info"))),
    Sasl = list_to_atom(couch_config:get("log", "include_sasl", "true")),

    case ets:info(?MODULE) of
    undefined -> ets:new(?MODULE, [named_table]);
    _ -> ok
    end,
    ets:insert(?MODULE, {level, Level}),

    case file:open(Filename, [append]) of %<<========open customzied file for logging
    {ok, Fd} ->
        {ok, {Fd, Level, Sasl}}; <<=========save the log file deviceIO into module state
    {error, eacces} ->
        {stop, {file_permission_error, Filename}};
    Error ->
        {stop, Error}
    end.

debug(Format, Args) ->
    {ConsoleMsg, FileMsg} = get_log_messages(self(), debug, Format, Args),
    gen_event:sync_notify(error_logger, {couch_debug, ConsoleMsg, FileMsg}). <=====generate customized logging message

handle_event({couch_debug, ConMsg, FileMsg}, {Fd, LogLevel, _Sasl}=State) <====handle the message
when LogLevel =< ?LEVEL_DEBUG ->
    log(Fd, ConMsg, FileMsg),
    {ok, State};

log(Fd, Pid, Level, Format, Args) ->
    Msg = io_lib:format(Format, Args),
    ok = io:format("[~s] [~p] ~s~n", [Level, Pid, Msg]), % dump to console too
    Msg2 = re:replace(lists:flatten(Msg),"\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "\r\n",
        [global, {return, list}]),
    ok = io:format(Fd, "[~s] [~s] [~p] ~s\r~n", [httpd_util:rfc1123_date(), Level, Pid, Msg2]).

log(Fd, ConsoleMsg, FileMsg) ->
    ok = io:put_chars(ConsoleMsg),
    ok = io:put_chars(Fd, FileMsg).  <=====write the log into file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try [lager](https://github.com/basho/lager) from basho folks, It's a good library for logging in erlang.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [alogger](https://github.com/siberian-fast-food/alogger) for Great Good!